# python guess game: help the player on the correct answer

Tags: python

hellow, I'm confused about writing this exercise from my book, can you please help me.
So far I have managed to write this amount:

```py
import random
       def main():
           again = 'y'
           number_of_guesses = 0

           while again =='y':
               print('guess the number game')
               print(' ')
               print('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses: ')
        
               x = random.randrange(1,1000)
               guess = int(input())
    
               while guess !='':
                   if guess < x:
                       print('Your guess is too low , try again')
                       guess = int(input())
                
                   elif guess > x:
                       print('Your guess is too high , try again')
                       guess = int(input())
                
                   elif guess == x:
                       print('Congratulations! You guessed the number')
                       print('Do you want to repeat?')
                       print('if you want do, type y, else type the n')
                       number_of_guesses += 1
                       again = str(input(''))
                
                       break
                    else:
                       print('Error/!\, your enter is wrong:')
main()
```

The main text of the question: as appropriate **to help the player “zero in” on the correct answer, then prompt the user for the next guess. When the user enters**
the correct answer, display "Congratulations. You guessed the number!", and allow the
user to choose whether to play again.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Does it provide unexpected results, throw an error, what? After fixing the indentation issues, the code looks to run as expected.

Comment: this part of question that say "to help the player “zero in” on the correct answer", I dont understand it,

Answer (score 0):

your code is all ok! What's the deal? Check the indentations if still wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you already solve the problem, where exactly you need help?
And instead of putting

```
while guess !+ '':
```

I would put

```
while True:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only multiple [indentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/) errors. Fixed version would be as follows:

```
import random
def main():
   again = 'y'
   number_of_guesses = 0

   while again =='y':
       print('guess the number game')
       print(' ')
       print('Guess my number between 1 and 1000 with the fewest guesses: ')

       x = random.randrange(1,1000)
       guess = int(input())

       while guess !='':
           if guess < x:
               print('Your guess is too low , try again')
               guess = int(input())

           elif guess > x:
               print('Your guess is too high , try again')
               guess = int(input())

           elif guess == x:
               print('Congratulations! You guessed the number')
               print('Do you want to repeat?')
               print('if you want do, type y, else type the n')
               number_of_guesses += 1
               again = str(input(''))
               break
           else:
               print('Error/!\, your enter is wrong:')
main()
```